# About the measurability of unbounded function on interval

Tags: integration, measure-theory, self-learning

I was asked if a real function $f$ on $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with countably many points of discontinuity is  $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$- measurable.

If $f$ were bounded, I know it's Riemann/Lebesgue integrable, meaning that it is measurable.

1. What if $f$ were unbounded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the answer for the bounded case, then the unbounded case can be easily resolved by considering $g(x) = \arctan(f(x))$ instead. ($f$ is measurable if and only if $g$ is measurable.)

Comment: I cannot understand your answer. Your example covers all cases where $f$ is unbounded on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Harumi, Yes. $\arctan(f(\cdot)) : [a, b] \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is bounded for *any* function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, and moreover, $f$ is measurable if and only if $\arctan(f(\cdot))$ is measurable. So you can first show that $\arctan(f(\cdot))$ is measurable and then use this to conclude that $f$ is also measurable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know these results. So the assumption that $f$ be bounded is not needed.

Comment: It looks that $arctan (f)$ has at most as many discontinuity points as $f$ has. So I could apply the result for bounded functions.

Comment: @Harumi, That is true :) The idea here is that both continuity and Borel measurability depend only on topologies, and so, it is conserved under homeomorphisms. In this case, we used the homeomorphism $\arctan : \mathbb{R} \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.