# Points of discontinuity of composition of continuous and discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

This question is related to a [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345290/about-the-measurability-of-unbounded-function-on-interval/3345319?noredirect=1#comment6885812_3345319) one.

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has countably many discontinuous points and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is a countinous function ($g=\arctan$). What to say about the points of discontinuity of $g\circ f=\arctan(f)$?

My thoughts are that there are at most as many points of discontinuity as $f$ has. Is it true?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's true because if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then also $g\circ f$ is.

Comment: and if $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, then $g\circ f$ is continuous or discontinuous at $x_0$. Right?

Comment: Yes, it could be that $g\circ f$ is continuous at points of discontinuity of $f$.

Comment: @Harumi That's a vacuous statement, because of course at any $x_0$, either $g\circ f$ is continuous or it's discontinuous. If what you mean is that either one is possible, then yes. For instance if $g = \text{id}$, then $g\circ f=f$ so $g\circ f$ is discontinuous wherever $f$ is discontinuous. But if $g=0$, then $g\circ f = 0$ which is continuous even where $f$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(a)$, then $g\circ f$ is continuous at $a$.

Since your $g$ is continuous everywhere, it follows that $g \circ f$ is continuous at every point where $f$ is continuous. Said another way, if $g \circ f $ is discontinuous at $a$, then so is $f$. So yes, your conclusion is correct.